# Replace specific values in a dataframe by column mean in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop

I'm a python beginner and I'm trying to do some operations with dataframes that I usually do with R language.

I Have a large dataframe with 2592 rows and 205 columns and I want to replace the 0.0 values by half the minimum value of its column.

An example with a random dataframe would be:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.random.seed(1)
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,10, size=(3,5)), columns = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'])
>>> print(df)
   A  B  C  D  E
0  5  8  9  5  0
1  0  1  7  6  9
2  2  4  5  2  4
```

And the result I'm looking for is:

```
   A  B  C  D  E
0  5  8  9  5  2
1  1  1  7  6  9
2  2  4  5  2  4
```

Intuitively I would do it like this:

```
>>> for column in df:
        for element in column:
            if element == 0:
                element = df[column].min()/2
```

But it doesn't work... any help?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html) with replace minimum values without `0` divide by `2`:

```
df1 = df.mask(df.eq(0), df.replace(0, np.nan).min().div(2), axis=1)
print(df1)
   A  B  C  D  E
0  5  8  9  5  2
1  1  1  7  6  9
2  2  4  5  2  4
```

For more efficient solution is possible use (thanks @mozway):

```
m = df.eq(0) 
df1 = df.mask(m, df[~m].min().div(2), axis=1)
```

Comment: `m = df.ne(0) ; df.where(m, df[m].min().div(2), axis=1)` would be a bit more efficient

Comment: why in your first expression the min is the column min and not the df min?

Comment: @AntonioMonteroLuque - no, it is not `min` column. `df.replace(0, np.nan)` - replace 0 to NaNs and then is called `min` function

Comment: Ok I got it thank you very much!! I know this is a more "pythonic" way to solve it but I wanted to understand how to do it with a for loop

Comment: another question: what do the "~" symbol?

Comment: @AntuanRage - it is inverting mask, practically `m = pd.Series([True, False, True])` after `~m` ouput is `m = [False, True, False]`

Comment: @AntuanRage - It working like `m == False`

Answer (score 1):

To work on your "intuitive" way, this is how to do it.

Use a function to perform the fancy logics you need.
Pandas has .apply function is optimised, so it should be sufficiently fast anyway.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(1)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,10, size=(3,5)), columns = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'])

def make_half_minimum(value, dataseries):
    if value == 0:
        dataseries_ = dataseries[dataseries!=0]
        return dataseries_.min()/2
    else:
        return value

for column_name in df.columns:
    df[column_name] = df[column_name].apply(lambda x: make_half_minimum(x,df[column_name]))

print(df)
```

```
     A  B  C  D    E
0  5.0  8  9  5  2.0
1  1.0  1  7  6  9.0
2  2.0  4  5  2  4.0
[Finished in 521ms]
```

Comment: "*Pandas has .apply function is optimised*" -> not sure what you mean by that, but this is wrong. `apply` is slow compared to vectorial code

Comment: Thank you Jake! its posible to do an "if condition" within a for loop?